# Azure Functions: binding to DocumentClient versus static instance - what's recommended?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I know how to bind queries directly to an Azure Function and use Cosmos DB triggers in functions.

However, I'm looking for direction around using `DocumentClient` (Nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`) directly.

1. There's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/cosmos-db?tabs=csharp#customize-a-documentclient-and-reuse-it-between-executions) that explains how to reuse a static client instance between executions.
2. It is also possible to get a `DocumentClient` instance as a binding by adding `[DocumentDB("test", "test", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDB")] DocumentClient client` to the function's parameters.
3. Finally, it is possible to create a `DocumentClient` instance in the function's body: `var client = new DocumentClient(...)`.

I do not find a clear recommendation when to use what approach except that number 3 never is a good option because of performance, memory usage and connection limits. Also, I understand that using a static instance has advantages.

**Questions**

- Azure functions have a connection limit ([discussed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections)). Does this also apply when using approach 2 (bind to client)?
- What are the pros and cons of using approach 2 (binding) versus 1 (static)?
- What's the advantage of binding to a SQL query compared to binding to a `DocumentClient` and creating the query in the function's body?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is another way to use DocumentClient.
Starting Version 1.0.28 of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, one can now use a FunctionsStartup class to initialize DocumentClient once, and then register it for DI (dependency injection), and then use the same instance every time.

The FunctionsStartup class is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection). And a better explanation is [here](https://blog.rasmustc.com/azure-functions-dependency-injection/).

In your Startup's configure method, build your client.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyApp.Startup))]
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            IDocumentClient client = GetCustomClient();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClient>(client);
        }
}
```

This can be then injected into the function constructor and used by the methods.

```
public class MyFunction
{
    private IDocumentClient _client;

    public MyFunction(IDocumentClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // use _client here.
    }
}
```

When Azure creates an instance of this class to serve a request, it passes the IDocumentClient instance that was created in FunctionsStartup class.

This strategy allows one to reuse the same instance of DocumentClient. Singeton-ness of this client is not forced by making it static, but by making sure we only create it once. This also helps with testability as tests can inject a different instance of IDocumentClient.

Comment: Though I'm really thankful for learning about yet another way of using Azure functions, this does not answer any of my questions. :-)

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/AzureFunctions/Startup.cs   Sample from the team before moving everyone over to the new v4 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/azure-cosmos-db-functions-cookbook-static-client-874072aef28e) makes a good case for a static client.

> We all know the woes of this approach for the HttpClient (and if you
>   don’t, please read it right after this article!), and it has the exact
>   same effect here: If the Function is getting a high volume of
>   triggers, we not only will be penalizing the performance of our
>   database calls with the initialization overhead but the memory
>   consumption will raise and we might even incur in socket exhaustion
>   scenarios.

To your questions 2 and 3:
The big pro of using the binding is simplicity. All the creation of the clients etc is abstracted away from you. Con of this is of course control. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/cosmos-db?tabs=csharp#customize-a-documentclient-and-reuse-it-between-executions) is a good example of using a custom client.

Using the SQL query instead of the DocumentClient is one step further up in regards to abstraction.

Comment: That blog post partially repeats what I wrote but it doesn't include all reasons: there's a connection limit. It does make a point of using a static instance but does not explain what the advantage over binding to `DocumentClient` is. I've also updated my question a bit.

Comment: `Using the SQL query instead of the DocumentClient is one step further up in regards to abstraction.` - isnt this backwards?