# Dependency Injection of Cosmos DB does not create documentClient object

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a service inside an azure function

```
    public MyService(
            IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider,
            ISerializationHelperService serializationHelperService,
            ICommandListBuilder commandListBuilder,
            [CosmosDB(
                StaticSettings.Db,
                StaticSettings.MyCollection.Collection,
                ConnectionStringSetting = StaticSettings.DbConnectionStringSetting)] IDocumentClient documentClient)
        {
            //my logic here - this does get hit
        }
```

My service is instantiated however, documentClient is null

How can I get this to be set properly?  I dont get any errors

I have checked and there are no issues with the connection settings

```
    public const string Db = "mydbname";
    public const string DbConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection";

    public static class MyCollection
    {
        public const string Collection = "mycollectionname";
        public static Uri CollectionUri => UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(Db, Collection);
    }
```

I am using a Startup class with an AddServices method to setup DI

Do I need to put something in there?

Paul

Comment: How does your `Startup` look like? In particular, are you sure there is an instance of `IDocumentClient` available in the service collection? You can break at the end of your `Startup.Configure` and traverse through `IFunctionsHostBuilder.Services`. If you can't find a `ServiceDescriptor` where `ServiceDescriptor.ServiceType.Name` is either `IDocumentClient` or `DocumentClient`, you know it's not registered and you'll have to add it yourself. Can't say I've used the Azure-specific attributes before for constructor injection, so don't know if you expect some magic to happen that I don't know of

Comment: I’m not sure what to put in the startup file I will take a look when I get back to my laptop. At the moment there is nothing specific there because the other function I have copied this from doesn’t have anything. Then again that is using diconfig rather than a startup class

Comment: How do you register your other services,`MyService`, `IConfigurationProvider`, etc? I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure there's no `IDocumentClient` registered as part of the default startup. You'll probably have to implement your own abstraction that'll initialize a DocumentClient and then expose the needed functionality via an interface you register in the service collection, and then inject that interface in `MyService`.

Comment: I found this answer here, that pretty much explains the exact same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287980/azure-functions-binding-to-documentclient-versus-static-instance-whats-recom

Answer (score 1):

I have Azure function v2 project and I'm able to inject all my dependencies. Below lines added for `IDocumentClient`

```
string databaseEndPoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DatabaseEndPoint");
        string databaseKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DatabaseKey");
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClient>(new DocumentClient(new System.Uri(databaseEndPoint), databaseKey,
            new ConnectionPolicy
            {
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
                RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),//Groupasset sync has some timeout issue with large payload
                // Customize retry options for Throttled requests
                RetryOptions = new RetryOptions()
                {
                    MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 5,
                    MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 60
                }
            }
        ));
```

**My Database Service**

```
protected readonly IDocumentClient client;

    protected BaseDao(IDocumentClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }
```

hope it will help!